# make function thread safe of class

Tags: multithreading, com, locking, atl

string getter & setter . How to make thread safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to end well even in a single-threaded program. `getString` hands out a pointer to storage managed by `strVar`. A later `setString` call may cause the string to reallocate its storage, leaving that pointer dangling. Any client that hangs onto this pointer and tries to use it at a later time will trigger undefined behavior.

Threads would make this issue worse. Say someone calls `getString` on one thread. It is possible that another thread calls `setString` and invalidates the pointer right after `getString` returns it and before its caller has a chance to actually use it. Putting a lock inside `getString` won't help prevent that. You need to return a copy of the shared state, not a pointer to the same.

And yes, reads and writes need to be synchronized. It's not enough to protect just the write with a lock - both have to occur under the lock, or else there's a data race.

Comment: I'm unable to parse this sentence, sorry.

Comment: Not the way `getString` is currently designed. It hands a pointer to the shared data out to the caller, and the caller has no choice but to access it unprotected, outside the lock.